# How to compress data on asp.net and uncompress in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, base64, deflate

Hi this is my first Question :)

I need a lib or way to compress a data in asp.net (vb) with the algorit deflate but the result inflate in javascript.

I'm use a lib in javascript: deflate.js
hxxp://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/Javascript_binaryenc.aspx?msg=2904739

First i'm deflate and convert to base64 the result but the result is no compatible with the javascript lib.

i'm use the Chilkat .NET DLL
hxxp://www.example-code.com/vbdotnet/deflate_string.asp

The String result with this lib is compatible with the javascript libray but is not free.

I need a way to compress data in asp.net and uncompress in javascript. This is for my web aplication need to download many many data.

P.D.: Sorry for my english :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of programming your custom solution, couldn't you simply enable HTTP compression on your web server? That way, compression/decompression would be automatically handled by the webserver and browser and your data is sent gzipped over the wire.

Comment: thanks. but the application is not mine is the company where I work and I only have access to the pages that they send me to do. By company policies nothing more I can edit the pages that I do, so she sought a solution that does not depend on global.asax or not covering the entire site because I do not have access to the entire site.

Answer (score 0):

Update of my post here is at:
http://pastie.org/1588170

-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

I use DEFLATE encoder and decoder implementation in Javascript at http://github.com/dankogai/js-deflate

I use Google's V8 Javascript engine ( url ) on server side to run Javascript code which I run on client side in web browser.